# accessing variable defined and set in code behind - on aspx page

Tags: vb.net

Sorry for such a basic question. I work in C# but have to do something on a site written in vb.net

In C# I can declare a variable and set it like this - in code behind.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string str = "Fred";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    str = "Jim";
    }
}
```

And, on the .aspx page, anywhere on the page I can write:

```
<% Response.Write(str) %>
```

and it will write "Jim" to the screen.

How do you do that in vb.net? I have ...

```
Public Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Public Ary As ArrayList
Public str As String

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Dim str as String
str = "Freda"
```

If I write <% Response.Write(str) %> on the .aspx page - nothing is written.

If I write <% Response.Write("Freda") %> on the .aspx page - it writes "Freda" to the screen.

In vb.net - what do you have to do to access variables set in the code behind, on the .aspx page?

I am not interested in setting the text value of a server control like a label etc. What I actually need to do is:

Get a list of images from a database call and

Build a dynamic jquery slider on the .aspx page by looping through the list of images and writing the various

tags and onclick events etc.

Sometimes my slider will have 3 pictures, other times it might have 6 or 8. Could be any number between 3 and 11. But I need to build it dynamically based on data returned from a database.

Comment: `Dim str as String` creates a *new* `str` variable local only to `Page_Load`.

Comment: So, how do you declare a Public String that is available to the .aspx page?

Comment: Doesnt it work if you just get rid of that line?  you have a global declaration already with `Public str As String`

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but whenever I need to convert C# to VB.NET or VB.NET to C#, I use the converter.telerik.com. You just paste you code in and then it converts it.

Comment: To Plutonix - yes that does work - if I remove the local declaration. What I want to do is publicly declare an ArrayList - so that I could loop through it on the .aspx page and dynamically generate a <ul> with a dynamic number of <li>s. So, I can add a public str and set str to "Fred" but if I add Public Ary As ArrayList then, in Page_Load write Ary.Add("fred") - it says 'object reference not set to an instance of an object'.
I read somewhere else to put <ul ID="myList" runat="server"></ul> and build the html dynamically. But it is not 'accessible due to its protection level'

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the Public string you should also define a default value.  For example:

```
Public str as String = "Fred"
```

Then in the Page_Load event you don't need to declare a new variable, simply reference the public variable like you did in C#:

```
str = "Freda"
```

Then when writing that to the output you would simply declare:

```
<%=str%>
```

However, if you are bringing through from a database would it not be best to use DataList object and build the HTML for the slider that way?

Answer (score 0):

If you define str before your page load, you will be able to access it throughout your class. Hopefully this helps.

```
Public Class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
Inherits BasePage

Dim str as String = ""

protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
{
    str = "Jim";
    Response.Write(str)

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.